# Cassandra and Graphite : GraphiteSender NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: cassandra, graphite

I have configured apache cassandra 3.7 to use graphite using metrics-graphite-2.2.0.jar (in the lib folder and the following metrics_reporter_graphite.yaml in /conf:

```
graphite:
-
    period: 30
    timeunit: 'SECONDS'
    prefix: 'cassandra-clustername-node1'
    hosts:
    - host: 'localhost'
        port: 2003
    predicate:
    color: "white"
    useQualifiedName: true
    patterns:
        - "^org.apache.cassandra.+"
        - "^jvm.+"
```

When starting Cassandra it fails within:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/codahale/metrics/graphite/GraphiteSender

Any help on this is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade to metrics-graphite-3.1.2.jar.

Answer (score 0):

you need to upgrade to metrics-graphite-3.1.0.jar , because in Cassandra 3.7 all dependent jars of metrics graphite comes up with 3.1.0 version only.(i.e. metrics-core-3.1.0.jar etc)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need the "metrics-graphite-3.1.2.jar".
You can download it from [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-graphite/3.1.2/metrics-graphite-3.1.2.jar)